# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'

Tags: linq

In this query I have 3 records **(int-(telefon =  d.telefon), decimal-(pesel = d.pesel), decimal-(nip = d.nip))** another records are strings.

```
public ActionResult detail(int LoginID)
{
    var user = (from d in baza.uzytkowniks
                where LoginID == d.LoginID
                select new uzytkownikModel {
                    imie = d.imie, 
                    nazwisko = d.nazwisko, 
                    telefon = d.telefon, 
                    pesel = d.pesel, 
                    nip = d.nip, 
                    email = d.email, 
                    adres_zamieszkania = d.adres_zamieszkania}).ToList();

    ViewBag.daneuser = user;
    return View();
}
```

And I have error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?)

and two another errors with 'decimal?' instead 'int?'.

Model:

```
 public class uzytkownikModel
    {
    [Required]
    public string imie { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string nazwisko { get; set; }


    public decimal pesel { get; set; }
    public decimal nip { get; set; }

    public string adres_zamieszkania { get; set; }
    public int telefon { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }

}
```

Only imie and nazwisko are nonnullable, rest have allow null

**///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////**

**Now work. I change in model:**

```
   decimal to decimal?
```

and

```
int to int?
```

Thank you everyone for help

Comment: why you dont show uzytkownikModel class? probably you getting that error becouse of fields or properties doesnt match with same type with your values.

Comment: can you post the definition of the type of 'd'?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your uzytkownikModel class, the properties that are nullable should be declared as "int?" or "decimal?" instead of "int" and "decimal".

Answer (score 41):

You'll need to post more code to get a definitive answer, but somewhere one of your variables is nullable, and to assign it to a non-nullable type you need to do `.Value`.

For example, *if* your object d's property `imie` is `Nullable<int>`, and that is what is causing your problem, you could do this:

```
imie = d.imie.Value
```

You will also need to watch for cases where `d.imie` is null.  For example:

```
imie = d.imie.HasValue ? d.imie.Value : 0
```

Or, if you like the ?? operator (which evaluates to the first non-null value):

```
imie = d.imie ?? 0
```

(I am just using `d.imie` as an example -- there is not enough code posted to pintpoint the exact problem.)

Comment: The d.imie.Value worked for me just like d.imie ?? 0; // Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

`int?` is the `Nullable<int>`.  Since database columns may be null, the mapped properties are Nullable.

Consider this code which assigns `int?` values to `int` variables.

```
int? w = 2;
int? x = null;
int y = w ?? 3;
int z = x ?? 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will work:

```
int ID = (int)(i.ID == null ? 0 : i.ID);
```