# EF 5 Is Ignoring [Required] Attribute On Int Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, attributes, entity

Entity Framework 5.0.0 seems to ignore the [Required] attribute when included on an int field and automatically includes a 0 value instead of throwing an exception. The required attribute does seem to work if the field is a string though. The simple model and create function below throws no exceptions. DbContext class with DbSet Degrees not shown for brevity.

```
public class Degree
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Field { get; set; }
}


private static void CreateDegree()
{
    var degree = new Degree { Name = "Mechanical Engineering" };
    var db = new Context();
    db.Degrees.Add(degree);

    // try statement
}
```

This maybe a simple misunderstanding on my part, but any thoughts / help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `[Required]` attribute indicates that a value must be present. When a `Degree` is constructed, `Field` is initialized to 0 because that is the default value for `int`s. Since 0 is a value, it satisfies the `[Required]` attribute.

You may want to try a `[Range]` attribute to specify that the value must be greater than 0. Or you could change the model to have an `int?`, so that it would be `null` unless it got initialized to some value.

Answer (score 7):

Your field is of type `int` which will always have a value.  When you create a new instance of the `Degree` class the `Field` property will be initialized to 0.

If you want the column to be nullable make the type of the property `int?`.  With a nullable type EF will throw an error if the value is `null`.

```
public class Degree
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int? Field { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This works fine, just beware that int? cannot be implicitly converted to type int. So you may have to change some of your code that references the Field integer. This can be handled a couple of ways here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053698/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-int-to-int