# Entity Framework 6 Code First - Required Enum data type not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, enumeration

I am generating a database table using an required enum field.
However, when feeding the table, it is possible to omit to feed the enum field: EF will not throw any error message but will feed the field with 0 value. Can you help me understanding what is happening?
Thanks

```
   public enum TestEnum {
        test1=1,
        test2=2,
        test3=3,
        test4=4
    }

public class TestEnumClass
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required"), Display(Name = "Test Enum")]
    public TestEnum test{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is because of how Enum types are handled in .NET. If you do not provide a value, it is effectively the same as if value 0 was assigned. If your enum has the value of 0 defined then the correct value is assigned to enum variable. If the value is not assigned - it still assigns value of 0 but it fails when you try to use it because it cannot convert the int to the correct enum value.

In your case I suggest if it is possible to add a value of 0 and assign it to a specific value or assign value of Default, Null or something similar to your enum, e.g.

```
public enum TestEnum {
    NotSet = 0,
    test1 = 1,
    test2 = 2,
    test3 = 3,
    test4 = 4
}
```

If you want to validate it then you can compare that value is not equals to 0.

Answer (score 35):

Use `RangeAttribute`:

```
public enum TestEnum
{
    test1 = 1,
    test2 = 2,
    test3 = 3,
    test4 = 4
}

public class TestEnumClass
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Range(1, 4), Display(Name = "Test Enum")]
    public TestEnum test{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I know this was three years ago and all, but this method duplicates information which likely would result in bugs down the line. For example, if I add test5 to `TestEnum`, I'd have to remember to change the range on any EF objects that have a `TestEnum` property.

Comment: @Joe: Set the validation attribute like this [Range(1, int.MaxValue), Display(Name = "Test Enum")], and you won't have any issues with future added enum-values unless an incorrect int-value is manually entered, if you really need to you can add custom validation to defend against these cases for instance by letting the TestEnumClass implement IValidateObject. The 0-value is a default value when no value is given, positive integers greater than zero have to manually be entered.

Answer (score 2):

Can you do it this way:

```
public class TestEnumClass
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required"), Display(Name = "Test Enum")]
    public TestEnum? test{ get; set; }
}
```

That is, define "test" to be nullable, but then mark it [Required] to force it to have a value.

[Similar discussion related to ints here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868017/ef-5-is-ignoring-required-attribute-on-int-type)